# 2D discrete cosine transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dct

I checked with `dct` function in Matlab but it only implemented DCT along the columns for a matrix input:

```
>> help dct 
If X is a matrix, the DCT operation is applied to each
column.
```

Is there a function that can perform 2D DCT in Matlab, or are there some algorithms that can apply `dct`, make some transform, then obtain the 2D DCT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform), "Multidimensional variants of the various DCT types follow straightforwardly from the one-dimensional definitions: they are simply a separable product (equivalently, a composition) of DCTs along each dimension."

Following this, you should be able to get the 2d-DCT by computing

```
dct(dct(A.').')
```

There's also `dct2` in the Image Processing Toolbox, and the core of the implementation is

```
b = dct(a, mpad);
if m > 1 && n > 1, b = dct(b.', npad).'; end
```

Comment: Thank you Donda. What's the meaning of dct(A.').' please? I don't quite understand the grammar of ').' here. In your dct2 implementation, does it mean you first dct on each column, and then on each row?

Comment: The operator is `.'`, and it stands for transposition without complement. The matrix `A` is first transposed, the DCT computed, the result transposed back, and the DCT computed again. This results in the 2d-DCT of `A`.

Comment: Maybe you got mislead by the syntax highlighting? It doesn't work correctly for Matlab, I'm afraid. The structure is `dct( dct( A .' ) .' )`.